# How to create an issue on gitlab (enterprise edition)?

Tags: gitlab, issue-tracking

When on the dashboard, on the left side bar, there is an entry "issues". When clicking on it, I reached to a page similar to [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues) one, except that the "new issue" green button on the top right is missing.

I searched documentation and all the admin area (I am connected as admin), without finding anything.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enter into a project first, then navigate to issues through left side bar.
2. If there is no issues entry in left side bar, enter into the "***Project settings***", under "***Features***" section, select "***Issues***" and save changes.

The "***Features***" section should look like this:

[image]

Comment: when visiting a project, the left side bar does not contain anything about issue ... (for example "Milestones" is there, but not "issues")

Comment: @Vince I have updated my answer, try to edit the project settings, select Issues feature and save changes, hope it would help.